# Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps failed to start on IOS, breaks in UpdateIsShowingUser

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps][1] is failing when deploying to IOS (in my case iPhone phisical device).
The app is trying to start but then crashes to the OS. Visual Studio does not catch the break point.

In the output window I get this:

> Loaded assembly:
> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BE8F87C7-8FB5-4F76-9674-03D160780B77/Documents/XFGoogleMapSampleiOS.content/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll
> [External] Loaded assembly:
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F4979BA1-4F02-476D-BB93-7A84EE654A10/XFGoogleMapSampleiOS.app/System.Xml.dll
> [External] Thread started:  #4 Thread started:  #5 Thread started:  #6 Thread started:  #7 Resolved pending breakpoint at 'BasicMapPage.xaml.cs:139,1'
> to void XFGoogleMapSample.BasicMapPage.<.ctor>b__0_15 (object sender,
> Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.CameraChangedEventArgs args) [0x00008].
> Loaded assembly:
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F4979BA1-4F02-476D-BB93-7A84EE654A10/XFGoogleMapSampleiOS.app/System.Net.Http.dll
> [External] Loaded assembly:
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F4979BA1-4F02-476D-BB93-7A84EE654A10/XFGoogleMapSampleiOS.app/System.Drawing.Common.dll
> [External] [0:] An error occurred: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'. Callstack: '  at
> Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.iOS.MapRenderer.UpdateIsShowingUser
> (System.Nullable`1[T] initialMyLocationButtonEnabled) <0x119727660 + 0x0007a> in <cae073484d4d4db5b36708f421f24080>:0    at Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.iOS.MapRenderer.OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e)
> <0x118649e28 + 0x002d0> in :0    at
> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) [0x00134] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:193    at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement
> (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00000] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:141    at
> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.CreateRenderer
> (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00014] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:199    at
> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded
> (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view) [0x0004f] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:79    at
> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x0001e] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:46    at
> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) [0x000f0] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:180    at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement
> (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00000] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:141    at
> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.CreateRenderer
> (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00014] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:199    at
> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded
> (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view) [0x0004f] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:79    at
> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x0001e] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:46    at
> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer.ViewDidLoad () [0x00086] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\PageRenderer.cs:123
> at (wrapper managed-to-native)
> ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper(intptr,intptr)   at
> UIKit.UIViewController.get_View () [0x0002a] in
> /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.2.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:3267
> at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer.get_NativeView () [0x00000]
> in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\PageRenderer.cs:41
> at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer.SetElement
> (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x0004f] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\PageRenderer.cs:56    at
> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.CreateRenderer
> (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00014] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:199    at
> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer.CreateViewControllerForPage
> (Xamarin.Forms.Page page) [0x00008] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:357
> at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer.OnPushAsync
> (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean animated) [0x0001d] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:344
> at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer.b__42_0
> (Xamarin.Forms.Page p) [0x00024] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:228
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__7_0
> (System.Object state) [0x00000] in
> /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1021
> at (wrapper delegate-invoke) .invoke_void_object(object)   at
> Foundation.NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000]
> in
> /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.2.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSAction.cs:178
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at (wrapper managed-to-native)
> UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)   at
> UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr
> principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in
> /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.2.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86
> at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String
> principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in
> /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.2.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65
> at XFGoogleMapSample.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args)
> [0x00001] in
> C:\Projects\Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps-master\XFGoogleMapSample\iOS\Main.cs:17
> at (wrapper managed-to-native)
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj,
> System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder
> binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo
> culture) [0x0006a] in
> /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/RuntimeMethodInfo.cs:395
> ' The app has been terminated.

First, I tried on my local project. After, I decided to get the source code of the googlemaps libray from git hub and debug it.
It breaks in the **MapRenderer.cs**

```
        private void UpdateIsShowingUser(bool? initialMyLocationButtonEnabled = null)
        {
#pragma warning disable 618
            ((MapView)Control).MyLocationEnabled = ((Map)Element).IsShowingUser;
            ((MapView)Control).Settings.MyLocationButton = initialMyLocationButtonEnabled ?? ((Map)Element).IsShowingUser;
#pragma warning restore 618
        }
```

Apparently the native Google.Maps.MapView.Settings is null here. I am not sure what exacly am I doing wrong, but the same library works perfect in Andoid version. It only fails in IOS.

I have set up API keys and API on google developer console.

- Visual Studio Version 16.7.7
- IOS 14.1
- Xamarin.iOS 14.2.0.12
  I also tried the standard xamarin google maps lirary and it works fine (it just miss many features comparing to Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps)
  [1]: https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps

Comment: See if following helps :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api

Comment: well, this not really help, since it is for Android. I am getting the issue deploying the app to IOS

Comment: I've the same issue. Not sure why yet. It works on simulator though. Please let me know if you came up with a solution.